# Converting LiDAR point cloud to 3D mesh

Tags: software-recommendations, lidar, las, tin, point-cloud

I have an unstructured point cloud of a street in LAS format (.las), scanned from a driving car. The point cloud also stores RGB information.

Is there any software that can convert the point cloud to a 3D mesh, for example FBX or OBJ?

I've tried:

- Autodesk Recap Pro - it doesn't work with unstructured point clouds.
- RealityCapture - it's not compatible with LAS format.
- Pix4D - it requires photos for reconstruction.

Answer (score 5):

Be aware that .las and .obj are not the same type of data, in which the first is composed by points, and the second is a type of surface.

So, even processing the point cloud to output a surface it is needed that the points in the .las file make sense to what is being generated. **For example, triangulating first returns (for DSM) or last returns, or returns from class 2 (for DTM).**

With that being said, it is possible with LAStools' [las2tin](https://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/download/las2tin_README.txt). See some examples:

Triangulates only first returns and stores the resulting TIN in OBJ (for DSM).

```
las2tin -i lidar.las -first_only -o tin.obj
```

The same, but triangulates only returns classified as ground (class 2, for DTM).

```
las2tin -i lidar.las -o tin.obj -keep_class 2
```

Answer (score -1):

I know it is an old thread, but for what it is worth: Agisoft Metashape does it.